# Does the proclamation of the New Moon by Beis Din have an effect on nature?

Tags: calendar, beit-din-court, blood, natural-phenomenon

I found in this celebratory volume, p 172 (haoros.com/download.asp?kovetzID=1086&ext=pdf)

והנה הרא"ה בספר בדק הבית שלו הובא בש"ך יור"ד סי' קפ"ט סקי"ג
הסכים עם קושיית הרמב"ן, ולפיכך כתב שיש קביעות וסת לימי החודש אבל
לא כשיטת הראב"ד, שהוא לפי ימי החודש שאנו מונים, שהרי אי אפשר שיהיה
קידוש החודש גורם לאשה שתראה דם, אלא לפי מולד הלבנה, והיינו שמונים
מספר הימים שעברו ממולד הלבנה עד היום שראתה בו, ואם ראתה ג' פעמים
בימים שוים לפי מולד הלבנה, קבעה וסת. אבל הרשב"א במשמרת הבית כתב
הובאו דבריו בש"ך שם) שודאי קביעת בית דין את החודש גורם את קביעות)
הוסת, והכל נקבע לפי ימי החודש אם מלא אם חסר כפי תיקוני בית דין, שכל
מה שבית דין שלמטה עושים בית דין שלמעלה מסכימים עמהם, ואף בחידושי
הגוף כן, כמו שדרשו חז"ל בירושלמי כתובות בפסוק לא-ל גומר עלי – קטנה
בת ג' שנים ויום אחד שנבעלה אין בתוליה חוזרים, נמנו בית דין ועיברו את
השנה – בתוליה חוזרים, וכן לכל ענין. וכן משמע פשט דברי הטור והשו"ע
והפוסקים – וכ"ה בשו"ע אדמו"ר הזקן הלכות נדה סי' קפד סקי"ב, סי' קפט
סקכ"ג

The question being dealt with is about fixing the date when a woman is expected to see a discharge of blood. There is a concept of “veses hachodesh”. This means that if she has seen for three successive months on the same day of the month, we can expect her to see again on the next month on the same day.

The רא"ה holds that it is impossible to think that the date can be fixed by the fixing of the date by the Beis Din (when the new moon was announced in that way) and we will have to rely on the real date of the first appearance of the moon.

The רשב"א on the other hand writes that we use the date when the new moon was proclaimed by the Beis Din and so also the nature of the woman depends on the sanctification of the month by the Beis Din.
Because everything that the Beis Din decrees in this world, the Beis Din above agrees to. 
And he brings another example of the same phenomenon.

The conclusion is that the Tur, the Shulchan Oruch and the Poskim and the Shulchan Oruch HoRav all agree to this principle that nature is dictated to by the actions of Beis Din. The view of the רא"ה is not accepted in Halacha.

How can I square this concept with the normal assumption of the operation of “nature”? Is it reasonable to think that this only applied in the times when the new month was proclaimed by Beis Din and in those  exalted times, nature was controlled by Beis Din?

Comment: Ruling like the Rashba regarding Veset needn't indicate acceptance of that explanation. Moreover, the fact that we Paskin like it is irrelevant, since if it were true, Paskining against it would make it not true, etc. (which is circular).

Comment: The simple explanation is that this is merely a legal principle. We worry about a Veset at legally prescribed times. We define various things based on the age of certain participants. That's a legal definition.

Comment: I remembervthis mishmeret habayit. May be that the "betulim chozrim is not a physiological rule". as 2 searot and 13 years and one day

Comment: Note that the actual moon doesn't affect menstruation either.

Comment: see discussion and sources at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18767/759 If paskining that mashiach must come now really worked, why did no one try it till now? Basically it's not as Muchrach as some claim. also related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20194/rosh-hashana-cant-currently-land-on-a-friday-but-the-first-one-did/20232#comment47553_20194

Comment: See Niddah 38a שיפורא גרים

Comment: Isn't there a Gemara regarding Adar Beis pushing off a girl's third birthday and that altering nature legabei simanei besulah?

Comment: @doni it's a yerushalmi and it's referenced in the Hebrew part of this post. That said it's not like a woman's body is so different at 3 and one day than the day before. We must be talking about a legal definition of Betulah.

Comment: @DoubleAA You have two comments here that we must be talking about a legal definition. Can you post this as an answer please (with sources for that view)?